# How to register setInterval without the delay without using any function as I need it to run 1st time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
var interval = setInterval(function(){alert("I am alive.")},delay)
```

I  want to register my setInterval explicitly as I want to run the interval after every delay time even if the page in which I have written it is destroyed. Which actually works fine if my delay is 5 minutes and I wait till the setInterval is registered for the first time then even if I change the page I get the alerts. But if I change the page before delay time then I dont get alert as it is never registered at all. So is there any way where I can directly register setInterval as soon as I load the page.

Comment: window.onload = function() {
  var interval = setInterval(function(){alert("I am alive.")},delay)
};

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting it a document ready? So when the page loads itll run straight away;

```
var interval;

$(document).ready(function) {
    interval = setInterval(function(){alert("I am alive.")},delay);    
});
```

Comment: I think he means $(document).ready(function() { ... SetInterval });